# How to solve this error on Rails: "Couldn't digest ActiveSupport::SafeBuffer"

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

There is an annoying "couldn't digest ActiveSupport::SafeBuffer" error being thrown on my local server. Here I am adding the whole trace:

https://nimbus.everhelper.me/client/notes/share/146831/DLovGG7C4NpLo2R9yTTi5G1xUG4cpJTS/

https://nimbus.everhelper.me/client/notes/share/146832/FOFP8lwX0HzASXeRh1pTxS9Q700OmtAN/

Anybody has an idea about how to solve this issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new Sprockets has problems loading .coffee.erb files like this one:

```
.state('dashboard', {url: '/users/dashboard', templateUrl: '<%= asset_path("users/dashboard.html") %>', controller: 'DashboardController'})
```

My workaround at the moment is to use Gulp instead of the asset pipeline.

Answer (score 2):

This might also be caused by a gem upgrade if you checkout and older version/SHA of your code.  In that case you want to remove your tmp directory, so within your Rails checkout folder do `rm -rf tmp`